# Is it possible to display QUICK EDIT as default for all posts in wp-admin/edit.php page?

Tags: posts, wp-admin

When we visit wp-admin/edit.php it display the post link. If we need a edit a post we need to click QUICK EDIT Link or Edit Link.

Is it possible to display QUICK EDIT as default for all posts in wp-admin/edit.php page?

Edit : After reading a comment I though my question is not clear. Just please read the below part.

> I need to click "quick edit" link to collapse the quick edit area. I
>   need to automatically collapse quick edit area when page loading for ALL POSTS.

Comment: what do you mean "display as default"? it is already there by default?

Comment: @majick Yes, but I need to click "quick edit" link to collapse it. I need to automatically  collapse  quick edit area when page loading for all posts.

Comment: I think you mean expand rather than collapse since they are collapsed by default too? I don't think this is possible since quick edit seems to load via AJAX and is dynamically inserted into the edit page for one post at a time.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I mean expand...

Comment: depending on what you want edit access to, you might find a plugin that adds an editable column or has more controls on the edit screen eg, admin management xtended... otherwise you'd have to write your own jQuery function based on the existing quick edit one to make it possible.